# How to add a record into Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-storage

In my application, I am able to take a screenshot from my cameras. Then I upload images to Firebase storage and get a download link. Now, I want to add this link to my database. I am able to do that by the following code:

```
fun storeImageUrlToFBDatabase(userId: String, cameraName: String, imageUrl: String) {
    val map = mapOf(cameraName to imageUrl)
    val ref = getFBDatabaseReference().getReference("users/$userId/images")
    ref.setValue(map)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Logger.d("$FB_DATABASE_TAG, Write was successful, $it")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Logger.e("$FB_DATABASE_TAG, Write failed: $it")
        }
}
```

This is what Firebase shows:
[image]

However, the problem is the current item under `images` will be replaced by a new item I am pushing in. My expectation is something like this:

- camera-streaming

  - users
  - userX

    - auth

      - token: "xxx"
      - userId: "xxxx"
    - images

      - image1: "url1"
      - image2: "url2"
      - image3: "url3"
      - image4: "url4"

But, what I get after each push/insert under `images` is having only one item/record. What is the problem?

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma, you are absolutely right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, all the best. B-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use key value to store the new links. This can be done in two ways:

1. Keep track of the current image sequence in the DB and then push the next value like:

val ref = getFBDatabaseReference().getReference("users/$userId/images");

```
//you need to find next xth image somehow

ref.child('imagex').setValue("map");
```

2. Just push the link to thee random key generated by DB:

val ref = getFBDatabaseReference().getReference("users/$userId/images");

```
val newRef = ref.push();
newRef.setValue("map");
```